# Iterating Java Arrays in Java 8

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

So here's a simple algorithmic problem,

> Given an array of n integers where n > 1, nums, return an array output
>   such that output[i] is equal to the product of all the elements of
>   nums except nums[i]. Solve it without division and in O(n). For
>   example, given [1,2,3,4], return [24,12,8,6].

Here's my solution,

```
public static int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {

    int[] result = new int[nums.length];

    int leftProduct = 1;
    int rightProduct = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        result[i] = leftProduct;
        leftProduct *= nums[i];
    }

    for(int i=nums.length -1; i >= 0; i --){
        result[i] *= rightProduct;
        rightProduct *= nums[i];
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] output = productExceptSelf(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
    Arrays.stream(output).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This works fine. What I'm trying to learn is how to rewrite this code in Java 8. As in what the different options with the loops in Java 8.

Comment: The above code is perfectly valid in Java 8.

Comment: @JoeC I kinda know that, my point is how can I rewrite the code using Java 8 functional constructs.

Comment: To be totally honest, this particular example is one which I would *not* attempt to do this.  This is largely because you are manipulating multiple variables inside your loop, and the `Stream` API is not designed very well for this.

Comment: Streams are not very suited (as they are now) to let temporary results flow into the further stream IMHO - **an unfortunate waste of time for everybody.**. Tip: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));` is nicer looking.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it in a few lines of code a bit different:

```
public static int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    int all = Arrays.stream(nums).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x * y);
    return IntStream.range(0, nums.length).map(x -> all / nums[x]).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution but the requirement was: *Solve it without division and in O(n)*

Comment: @Flown I have absolutely done the skim reading over the question and did not even noticed :(

Answer (score 3):

Several comments and answers have mentioned that the streams API doesn't lend itself to solving this sort of problem. I agree; it's much easier to work with arrays. Here's how I'd do it:

```
static int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    int len = nums.length;

    int[] lefts = new int[len];
    Arrays.setAll(lefts, i -> i == 0 ? 1 : lefts[i-1] * nums[i-1]);

    int[] rights = new int[len]; // reversed
    Arrays.setAll(rights, i -> i == 0 ? 1 : rights[i-1] * nums[len-i]);

    int[] result = new int[len];
    Arrays.setAll(result, i -> lefts[i] * rights[len-i-1]);

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(productExceptSelf(nums)));
}
```

This is conceptually quite similar to the iterative approach, but it stores full intermediate results in temporary arrays in order to take advantage of the `Arrays.setAll` operation. This takes more space, but it does the same number of multiplications.

I note that the specification of `Arrays.setAll` doesn't guarantee left-to-right opreation, but this approach requires it. In fact, `setAll` is basically a wrapper for `IntStream.range(0, length)`, so you could easily write this utility yourself if this dependence on `setAll` is a concern.

Note that this is basically a "prefix" or "scan" operation, as illustrated in [Flown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010844/1441122). (+1) Unfortunately, the limitations of `Arrays.parallelPrefix`, such as inability to specify an initial element, and the inability to scan right-to-left (and also the lack of a built-in way to reverse a primitive array) make that approach inconvenient, though sound.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you ask, but I feel like it needs more elegance :-D

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> output = productExceptSelf(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
    output.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<Integer> productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(value -> {
        int x = 1;
        for (Integer i : list) {
            if (value.equals(i)) continue;
            x *= i;
        }
        results.add(x);
    });
    return results;
}
```

Comment: The OP had an already very nice solution. This time your solution seems not to do the same, the first element being 24.

Comment: @JoopEggen care to point out where the error lies? I ran some test cases and they seem to do fine.

Comment: apologies! The solution itself is fine and to the point, but not O(N), it is O(N²). And I would have wished more stream things. Still I should have said so.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments: `Stream`s are not well suited for this kind of task, but there are other methods in the JDK, like `Arrays::parallelPrefix`.

I took your idea and transformed it into:

```
private static int[] productExceptSelf(int[] arr) {
  IntBinaryOperator product = (a, b) -> a * b;

  int[] leftPrefix = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(1), IntStream.of(arr)).toArray();
  Arrays.parallelPrefix(leftPrefix, product);

  int[] reversedRightPrefix = reversed(IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(arr), IntStream.of(1))
                                             .toArray());
  Arrays.parallelPrefix(reversedRightPrefix, product);
  //Could be calculated on-the-fly: reversedRightPrefix[reversedRightPrefix - i - 2]
  int[] rightPrefix = reversed(reversedRightPrefix);

  return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                 .map(i -> product.applyAsInt(leftPrefix[i], rightPrefix[i + 1]))
                 .toArray();
}

private static int[] reversed(int[] arr) {
  return IntStream.range(0, arr.length).map(i -> arr[arr.length - 1 - i]).toArray();
}
```

Since you've asked for loop alternatives you can use recursion (still Java 8 code):

```
private static int[] productExceptSelf(int[] arr) {
  int[] result = new int[arr.length];
  productExceptSelf(arr, result, 0, 1);
  return result;
}

private static int productExceptSelf(int[] arr, int[] result, int i, int leftPrefix) {
  if (arr.length <= i) {
    return 1;
  }
  int rightPrefix = productExceptSelf(arr, result, i + 1, leftPrefix * arr[i]);
  result[i] = leftPrefix * rightPrefix;
  return rightPrefix * arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Plus one for use of `Arrays.parallelPrefix`.